# How to manually create a three-by-three-by-three NumPy array using a combination of np.array() and np.arange(3)?

Tags: python, numpy

I am missing an approach to the following NumPy array. The goal is to manually create a three-by-three array. I have come this far:

```
m = np.array([[np.arange(3)], [np.arange(3)], [np.arange(3)]])
m
​
# Output:
array([[[0, 1, 2]],
​
       [[0, 1, 2]],
​
       [[0, 1, 2]]])

m.shape
# Output:
(3, 1, 3)
```

**Question: How must m be adapted so that m.shape becomes (3, 3, 3)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sublists should contain *three* `arange(3)`s:

```
# shape (3,3,3)
m = np.array([[np.arange(3), np.arange(3), np.arange(3)],
              [np.arange(3), np.arange(3), np.arange(3)],
              [np.arange(3), np.arange(3), np.arange(3)]])
```

This is a three-by-three-by-three array. If you want a three-by-three array, you only need to construct *one* list with three `arange(3)`s:

```
# shape (3,3)
m = np.array([np.arange(3), np.arange(3), np.arange(3)])
```

But it might be easier to use a function like [**`np.tile(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for this:

```
# shape (3,3,3)
np.tile(np.arange(3), (3,3,1))
```

or for a three-by-three array:

```
# shape (3,3)
np.tile(np.arange(3), (3,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that squeeze() would be easier

```
> m = np.array([[np.arange(3)], [np.arange(3)], [np.arange(3)]])
> m
> 
> array([[[0, 1, 2]],
> 
>        [[0, 1, 2]],
> 
>        [[0, 1, 2]]])
> 
> m.shape 
> (3, 1, 3)
> 
> s = m.squeeze()
> s 
> array([[0, 1, 2],
>        [0, 1, 2],
>        [0, 1, 2]])
> s.shape
> (3, 3)
```